# Google Maps encoded polyline not showing as expected

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create an encoded polyline of all Canadian provinces. I begun with this utility:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility

Using it I create many point to follow the province line of ontario as closely as possible. Here's a screenshot of the resulting polyline:

[image: Polyline Utility Result]

but when I take the polyline an plug it into the code to map it, It provides me with partially different line:

http://jsfiddle.net/2x6eLLca/1/

```
    <html> 
<head> 
<title>Test</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<style type="text/css"> 
#map {width:670px;height:600px;}
</style> 
<script type='text/javascript'>
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(61.5780305,-107.1029399);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    var decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath('wkllHvswcQ_N`Kgl@jDJuEyIwIgv_TYuymWyusd@wbOqcLrgd@yvn@fqsH_ulc@iuMgppAhoWixv@v|oC}vXf`uD_{K`idAp}gApjkCynyCtwmB_`rIlobYsia@tmlFex}CtiiDov{Ov`KivImrH_gSc]gsDwhE}gAcc@{rBer@szI{zH{q_@_EufFkpDsoSicFi}L_EydG`r@slC~AygLeiCqsQcmG{eM~S_[_Bi`]dqHwgWdlCg}Wfnr@rhPpdWi`]hlGn|SnnMf_Lt_D`gShpEzgLni@~qIjc@puE}pAtcAaEfsDkc@zyEbxD|aObNbwMhmG~xLnuBraMpxBnr@jaItw\bkA`dCto@ucAtrBhqEcHvv@x{BfuCvrBn~Gd`y@nolAtrGtcA`gPpf\gv@~lEdxHnuP~i@xbHhaBzpCdaGqGbpEzeM`j@zpN|bKjdEr{F`~Pr|xAtkcAzWrjtJzwb@pn~Ajfe@}oUvbT_mE`oCrjDnpAor@nnDtcAvvAgaK~cAytAhtE|pCdbDePfnEivIfq@ujDr|BabDdhEeP`qLx{Df{sAvl~Ethc@vh`FxvfBlf_F?ra{@web@f{fAouc@~hRm|O_mEcaTnr@ohLq|HidConModBgaK{cDcaV{f`@_e_@{hBa`EfiAy}Cch@adCivDaqD{qC_mEukJcjA_gIohD}nB?afDq_BiwGtrAc{NyeAwlHw_C_tFi`F_pBbjAqfBk_AoupB}~w@iusIfbjAwr}Ar{rEwab@sb^ibSnjZxVrpd@`yFrtWxVngJchXncW{wSrqGgpCzKs_@glA_|HhqEs~HlTk~NmdEqxCrnBuS|gAn\tjDunAduChh@jdEdqFjoF|AhoFykAn`GuSb~E~bAzrB}D|pC|bAv}Ct|EtjDet@~aOmn`@vjg@i{p@tdR{rsGbbkT~wJff}@zjt@jc~BgpFnq]lx@fyYyqBtb^tmE|aOwvDttWwnOhoFzUpuaBcg@fsD{kBucApr@~zKhx@pnBvzAfvTklGpuEka@flAix@qnB_fBwIvXrnBsxB|x@eFnpA{_@zKl@zZre@gChWdn@aS`]ikHlEayAtIgM`]sQzZvl@fdDik@`{@npApwDvjAfaKjqBrjDjiA`bDrGjfDzi@b{@hCbhBxl@xv@vb@zaCxl@nc@|_@hwCha@se@liDj|GwNfn@|iCr{Chn@njC`~@|gAte@pnBve@`aJdPtcAaSd_@`]r{C{Kvg@zmAl{Bnu@joFaI|x@owBf}@|Kn_BiC`sC`wCplNma@rt@irG}i@{v@ycBgn@`l@rfArwPa}BjdElJ`bDsvIia@dP|pCujDsnBozAtmTp[jkHcgEbbDfa@pcLehCwXlJ~eBz}@vX{eBnpA_ShjB_uJia@eiArqGayCxtAjr@nyCub@xzJ{z@pGdu@~lEfa@?xUbyAqQ~gAx_@tIvDxeAiWlT_c@tbGxhArbDfsB`e@fMnaAjh@rGj|@urAnkBzi@nsCoaAvl@{cBpy@qVhk@`xGvl@zrB_IrVvjA`bDeFd_@lJiCvNvIsiCvaBePqFpBfQuNbHuDqJ}ItADeMwLxGiAzClEvQoAhNeKQx@sK{DaDsVpYmH}Ds`F`oC}Vf\ob@t_@yFnTlCtP}Vp]uLxJgYzKuAbCcbFlpD{zBni@itDi_CooA?kY`vBicAfn@{Fzi@qlBjkBT||Dbk@jpFrXbuNaU`l@eWt|CqvBvuCel@yYuOjDshAor@g~@_MkO_pAlF}xCca@al@jJok@V{h@xAyRsHwg@iOmSa[~[q]ki@cFtIgXcHsxCxz@eUpoC~i@xuLo_Jjy_@qBtrAmbAhyBwFt~BshC?oGd_@rp@pxDoXjsSj[nfPq^za@swAlqCoAldHxeB~kQ`~Avg@kOhh@`q@`{@vKxvCgd@r{@z~@lxC~`@ho@rHr{CzX~\xdCu|@ddB|Sf^vg@ng@prFhu@pmE|G`eC~OrnBqSxeArd@dzApGps@_u@flAxApd@p}@`{@zRre@`Kt`HaPbhBlEd|@cFvqBdRr`ByFre@UvhE_uAt|C__@bAk`@en@k{@tHosAcl@q_BtHexDf{AopBj|AyRhhCk[tlI`Kb^qBjaFmx@pkIvKnvDkQhmAj@hmAbAlTmQlTnLxv@xAl}AqNtu@lLjnAeMtyDpBbyAe^jaFbAz|AlFhtAka@`zCqo@nr@ueB_\_w@fXmeAp{@iDj_Aoc@rs@s[~`Dxc@xyBtEz|AmRl_Ds`@n_BbGdwE~_BdwBfN|uAka@`gEwQzyEsIntBykAjgA}Nn{EczBntEoj@heDm]}DomCpfE{YlnAgyIjnAut@qnBooDvg@yYse@efk@fpK_uBtjDs|c@xqH}yAucAeXf|FkrG~wRjNpfEtgAv}CpR|fGifAfiHgh@v|CsTnUabA`dC'); 
    var decodedLevels = decodeLevels("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB");

    var setRegion = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: decodedPath,
        levels: decodedLevels,
        strokeColor: '#8A8000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#8A8A1D',
        fillOpacity: 0,
        map: map
    });
}

function decodeLevels(encodedLevelsString) {
    var decodedLevels = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < encodedLevelsString.length; ++i) {
        var level = encodedLevelsString.charCodeAt(i) - 63;
        decodedLevels.push(level);
    }
    return decodedLevels;
}
</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="initialize()"> 
<div id="map"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

[image]

Any Ideas why the line deviates? I tried it twice, each time the line veers of midway.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the "\" characters in the string (replace the single "\" with a double "\\").

Change:

```
var decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath('wkllHvswcQ_N`Kgl@jDJuEyIwIgv_TYuymWyusd@wbOqcLrgd@yvn@fqsH_ulc@iuMgppAhoWixv@v|oC}vXf`uD_{K`idAp}gApjkCynyCtwmB_`rIlobYsia@tmlFex}CtiiDov{Ov`KivImrH_gSc]gsDwhE}gAcc@{rBer@szI{zH{q_@_EufFkpDsoSicFi}L_EydG`r@slC~AygLeiCqsQcmG{eM~S_[_Bi`]dqHwgWdlCg}Wfnr@rhPpdWi`]hlGn|SnnMf_Lt_D`gShpEzgLni@~qIjc@puE}pAtcAaEfsDkc@zyEbxD|aObNbwMhmG~xLnuBraMpxBnr@jaItw\bkA`dCto@ucAtrBhqEcHvv@x{BfuCvrBn~Gd`y@nolAtrGtcA`gPpf\gv@~lEdxHnuP~i@xbHhaBzpCdaGqGbpEzeM`j@zpN|bKjdEr{F`~Pr|xAtkcAzWrjtJzwb@pn~Ajfe@}oUvbT_mE`oCrjDnpAor@nnDtcAvvAgaK~cAytAhtE|pCdbDePfnEivIfq@ujDr|BabDdhEeP`qLx{Df{sAvl~Ethc@vh`FxvfBlf_F?ra{@web@f{fAouc@~hRm|O_mEcaTnr@ohLq|HidConModBgaK{cDcaV{f`@_e_@{hBa`EfiAy}Cch@adCivDaqD{qC_mEukJcjA_gIohD}nB?afDq_BiwGtrAc{NyeAwlHw_C_tFi`F_pBbjAqfBk_AoupB}~w@iusIfbjAwr}Ar{rEwab@sb^ibSnjZxVrpd@`yFrtWxVngJchXncW{wSrqGgpCzKs_@glA_|HhqEs~HlTk~NmdEqxCrnBuS|gAn\tjDunAduChh@jdEdqFjoF|AhoFykAn`GuSb~E~bAzrB}D|pC|bAv}Ct|EtjDet@~aOmn`@vjg@i{p@tdR{rsGbbkT~wJff}@zjt@jc~BgpFnq]lx@fyYyqBtb^tmE|aOwvDttWwnOhoFzUpuaBcg@fsD{kBucApr@~zKhx@pnBvzAfvTklGpuEka@flAix@qnB_fBwIvXrnBsxB|x@eFnpA{_@zKl@zZre@gChWdn@aS`]ikHlEayAtIgM`]sQzZvl@fdDik@`{@npApwDvjAfaKjqBrjDjiA`bDrGjfDzi@b{@hCbhBxl@xv@vb@zaCxl@nc@|_@hwCha@se@liDj|GwNfn@|iCr{Chn@njC`~@|gAte@pnBve@`aJdPtcAaSd_@`]r{C{Kvg@zmAl{Bnu@joFaI|x@owBf}@|Kn_BiC`sC`wCplNma@rt@irG}i@{v@ycBgn@`l@rfArwPa}BjdElJ`bDsvIia@dP|pCujDsnBozAtmTp[jkHcgEbbDfa@pcLehCwXlJ~eBz}@vX{eBnpA_ShjB_uJia@eiArqGayCxtAjr@nyCub@xzJ{z@pGdu@~lEfa@?xUbyAqQ~gAx_@tIvDxeAiWlT_c@tbGxhArbDfsB`e@fMnaAjh@rGj|@urAnkBzi@nsCoaAvl@{cBpy@qVhk@`xGvl@zrB_IrVvjA`bDeFd_@lJiCvNvIsiCvaBePqFpBfQuNbHuDqJ}ItADeMwLxGiAzClEvQoAhNeKQx@sK{DaDsVpYmH}Ds`F`oC}Vf\ob@t_@yFnTlCtP}Vp]uLxJgYzKuAbCcbFlpD{zBni@itDi_CooA?kY`vBicAfn@{Fzi@qlBjkBT||Dbk@jpFrXbuNaU`l@eWt|CqvBvuCel@yYuOjDshAor@g~@_MkO_pAlF}xCca@al@jJok@V{h@xAyRsHwg@iOmSa[~[q]ki@cFtIgXcHsxCxz@eUpoC~i@xuLo_Jjy_@qBtrAmbAhyBwFt~BshC?oGd_@rp@pxDoXjsSj[nfPq^za@swAlqCoAldHxeB~kQ`~Avg@kOhh@`q@`{@vKxvCgd@r{@z~@lxC~`@ho@rHr{CzX~\xdCu|@ddB|Sf^vg@ng@prFhu@pmE|G`eC~OrnBqSxeArd@dzApGps@_u@flAxApd@p}@`{@zRre@`Kt`HaPbhBlEd|@cFvqBdRr`ByFre@UvhE_uAt|C__@bAk`@en@k{@tHosAcl@q_BtHexDf{AopBj|AyRhhCk[tlI`Kb^qBjaFmx@pkIvKnvDkQhmAj@hmAbAlTmQlTnLxv@xAl}AqNtu@lLjnAeMtyDpBbyAe^jaFbAz|AlFhtAka@`zCqo@nr@ueB_\_w@fXmeAp{@iDj_Aoc@rs@s[~`Dxc@xyBtEz|AmRl_Ds`@n_BbGdwE~_BdwBfN|uAka@`gEwQzyEsIntBykAjgA}Nn{EczBntEoj@heDm]}DomCpfE{YlnAgyIjnAut@qnBooDvg@yYse@efk@fpK_uBtjDs|c@xqH}yAucAeXf|FkrG~wRjNpfEtgAv}CpR|fGifAfiHgh@v|CsTnUabA`dC');
```

To:

```
var decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath('wkllHvswcQ_N`Kgl@jDJuEyIwIgv_TYuymWyusd@wbOqcLrgd@yvn@fqsH_ulc@iuMgppAhoWixv@v|oC}vXf`uD_{K`idAp}gApjkCynyCtwmB_`rIlobYsia@tmlFex}CtiiDov{Ov`KivImrH_gSc]gsDwhE}gAcc@{rBer@szI{zH{q_@_EufFkpDsoSicFi}L_EydG`r@slC~AygLeiCqsQcmG{eM~S_[_Bi`]dqHwgWdlCg}Wfnr@rhPpdWi`]hlGn|SnnMf_Lt_D`gShpEzgLni@~qIjc@puE}pAtcAaEfsDkc@zyEbxD|aObNbwMhmG~xLnuBraMpxBnr@jaItw\\bkA`dCto@ucAtrBhqEcHvv@x{BfuCvrBn~Gd`y@nolAtrGtcA`gPpf\\gv@~lEdxHnuP~i@xbHhaBzpCdaGqGbpEzeM`j@zpN|bKjdEr{F`~Pr|xAtkcAzWrjtJzwb@pn~Ajfe@}oUvbT_mE`oCrjDnpAor@nnDtcAvvAgaK~cAytAhtE|pCdbDePfnEivIfq@ujDr|BabDdhEeP`qLx{Df{sAvl~Ethc@vh`FxvfBlf_F?ra{@web@f{fAouc@~hRm|O_mEcaTnr@ohLq|HidConModBgaK{cDcaV{f`@_e_@{hBa`EfiAy}Cch@adCivDaqD{qC_mEukJcjA_gIohD}nB?afDq_BiwGtrAc{NyeAwlHw_C_tFi`F_pBbjAqfBk_AoupB}~w@iusIfbjAwr}Ar{rEwab@sb^ibSnjZxVrpd@`yFrtWxVngJchXncW{wSrqGgpCzKs_@glA_|HhqEs~HlTk~NmdEqxCrnBuS|gAn\\tjDunAduChh@jdEdqFjoF|AhoFykAn`GuSb~E~bAzrB}D|pC|bAv}Ct|EtjDet@~aOmn`@vjg@i{p@tdR{rsGbbkT~wJff}@zjt@jc~BgpFnq]lx@fyYyqBtb^tmE|aOwvDttWwnOhoFzUpuaBcg@fsD{kBucApr@~zKhx@pnBvzAfvTklGpuEka@flAix@qnB_fBwIvXrnBsxB|x@eFnpA{_@zKl@zZre@gChWdn@aS`]ikHlEayAtIgM`]sQzZvl@fdDik@`{@npApwDvjAfaKjqBrjDjiA`bDrGjfDzi@b{@hCbhBxl@xv@vb@zaCxl@nc@|_@hwCha@se@liDj|GwNfn@|iCr{Chn@njC`~@|gAte@pnBve@`aJdPtcAaSd_@`]r{C{Kvg@zmAl{Bnu@joFaI|x@owBf}@|Kn_BiC`sC`wCplNma@rt@irG}i@{v@ycBgn@`l@rfArwPa}BjdElJ`bDsvIia@dP|pCujDsnBozAtmTp[jkHcgEbbDfa@pcLehCwXlJ~eBz}@vX{eBnpA_ShjB_uJia@eiArqGayCxtAjr@nyCub@xzJ{z@pGdu@~lEfa@?xUbyAqQ~gAx_@tIvDxeAiWlT_c@tbGxhArbDfsB`e@fMnaAjh@rGj|@urAnkBzi@nsCoaAvl@{cBpy@qVhk@`xGvl@zrB_IrVvjA`bDeFd_@lJiCvNvIsiCvaBePqFpBfQuNbHuDqJ}ItADeMwLxGiAzClEvQoAhNeKQx@sK{DaDsVpYmH}Ds`F`oC}Vf\\ob@t_@yFnTlCtP}Vp]uLxJgYzKuAbCcbFlpD{zBni@itDi_CooA?kY`vBicAfn@{Fzi@qlBjkBT||Dbk@jpFrXbuNaU`l@eWt|CqvBvuCel@yYuOjDshAor@g~@_MkO_pAlF}xCca@al@jJok@V{h@xAyRsHwg@iOmSa[~[q]ki@cFtIgXcHsxCxz@eUpoC~i@xuLo_Jjy_@qBtrAmbAhyBwFt~BshC?oGd_@rp@pxDoXjsSj[nfPq^za@swAlqCoAldHxeB~kQ`~Avg@kOhh@`q@`{@vKxvCgd@r{@z~@lxC~`@ho@rHr{CzX~\\xdCu|@ddB|Sf^vg@ng@prFhu@pmE|G`eC~OrnBqSxeArd@dzApGps@_u@flAxApd@p}@`{@zRre@`Kt`HaPbhBlEd|@cFvqBdRr`ByFre@UvhE_uAt|C__@bAk`@en@k{@tHosAcl@q_BtHexDf{AopBj|AyRhhCk[tlI`Kb^qBjaFmx@pkIvKnvDkQhmAj@hmAbAlTmQlTnLxv@xAl}AqNtu@lLjnAeMtyDpBbyAe^jaFbAz|AlFhtAka@`zCqo@nr@ueB_\\_w@fXmeAp{@iDj_Aoc@rs@s[~`Dxc@xyBtEz|AmRl_Ds`@n_BbGdwE~_BdwBfN|uAka@`gEwQzyEsIntBykAjgA}Nn{EczBntEoj@heDm]}DomCpfE{YlnAgyIjnAut@qnBooDvg@yYse@efk@fpK_uBtjDs|c@xqH}yAucAeXf|FkrG~wRjNpfEtgAv}CpR|fGifAfiHgh@v|CsTnUabA`dC');
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2x6eLLca/2/)

[image: fixed encoded polyline]

**code snippet:**

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(61.5780305, -107.1029399);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

  var decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath('wkllHvswcQ_N`Kgl@jDJuEyIwIgv_TYuymWyusd@wbOqcLrgd@yvn@fqsH_ulc@iuMgppAhoWixv@v|oC}vXf`uD_{K`idAp}gApjkCynyCtwmB_`rIlobYsia@tmlFex}CtiiDov{Ov`KivImrH_gSc]gsDwhE}gAcc@{rBer@szI{zH{q_@_EufFkpDsoSicFi}L_EydG`r@slC~AygLeiCqsQcmG{eM~S_[_Bi`]dqHwgWdlCg}Wfnr@rhPpdWi`]hlGn|SnnMf_Lt_D`gShpEzgLni@~qIjc@puE}pAtcAaEfsDkc@zyEbxD|aObNbwMhmG~xLnuBraMpxBnr@jaItw\\bkA`dCto@ucAtrBhqEcHvv@x{BfuCvrBn~Gd`y@nolAtrGtcA`gPpf\\gv@~lEdxHnuP~i@xbHhaBzpCdaGqGbpEzeM`j@zpN|bKjdEr{F`~Pr|xAtkcAzWrjtJzwb@pn~Ajfe@}oUvbT_mE`oCrjDnpAor@nnDtcAvvAgaK~cAytAhtE|pCdbDePfnEivIfq@ujDr|BabDdhEeP`qLx{Df{sAvl~Ethc@vh`FxvfBlf_F?ra{@web@f{fAouc@~hRm|O_mEcaTnr@ohLq|HidConModBgaK{cDcaV{f`@_e_@{hBa`EfiAy}Cch@adCivDaqD{qC_mEukJcjA_gIohD}nB?afDq_BiwGtrAc{NyeAwlHw_C_tFi`F_pBbjAqfBk_AoupB}~w@iusIfbjAwr}Ar{rEwab@sb^ibSnjZxVrpd@`yFrtWxVngJchXncW{wSrqGgpCzKs_@glA_|HhqEs~HlTk~NmdEqxCrnBuS|gAn\\tjDunAduChh@jdEdqFjoF|AhoFykAn`GuSb~E~bAzrB}D|pC|bAv}Ct|EtjDet@~aOmn`@vjg@i{p@tdR{rsGbbkT~wJff}@zjt@jc~BgpFnq]lx@fyYyqBtb^tmE|aOwvDttWwnOhoFzUpuaBcg@fsD{kBucApr@~zKhx@pnBvzAfvTklGpuEka@flAix@qnB_fBwIvXrnBsxB|x@eFnpA{_@zKl@zZre@gChWdn@aS`]ikHlEayAtIgM`]sQzZvl@fdDik@`{@npApwDvjAfaKjqBrjDjiA`bDrGjfDzi@b{@hCbhBxl@xv@vb@zaCxl@nc@|_@hwCha@se@liDj|GwNfn@|iCr{Chn@njC`~@|gAte@pnBve@`aJdPtcAaSd_@`]r{C{Kvg@zmAl{Bnu@joFaI|x@owBf}@|Kn_BiC`sC`wCplNma@rt@irG}i@{v@ycBgn@`l@rfArwPa}BjdElJ`bDsvIia@dP|pCujDsnBozAtmTp[jkHcgEbbDfa@pcLehCwXlJ~eBz}@vX{eBnpA_ShjB_uJia@eiArqGayCxtAjr@nyCub@xzJ{z@pGdu@~lEfa@?xUbyAqQ~gAx_@tIvDxeAiWlT_c@tbGxhArbDfsB`e@fMnaAjh@rGj|@urAnkBzi@nsCoaAvl@{cBpy@qVhk@`xGvl@zrB_IrVvjA`bDeFd_@lJiCvNvIsiCvaBePqFpBfQuNbHuDqJ}ItADeMwLxGiAzClEvQoAhNeKQx@sK{DaDsVpYmH}Ds`F`oC}Vf\\ob@t_@yFnTlCtP}Vp]uLxJgYzKuAbCcbFlpD{zBni@itDi_CooA?kY`vBicAfn@{Fzi@qlBjkBT||Dbk@jpFrXbuNaU`l@eWt|CqvBvuCel@yYuOjDshAor@g~@_MkO_pAlF}xCca@al@jJok@V{h@xAyRsHwg@iOmSa[~[q]ki@cFtIgXcHsxCxz@eUpoC~i@xuLo_Jjy_@qBtrAmbAhyBwFt~BshC?oGd_@rp@pxDoXjsSj[nfPq^za@swAlqCoAldHxeB~kQ`~Avg@kOhh@`q@`{@vKxvCgd@r{@z~@lxC~`@ho@rHr{CzX~\\xdCu|@ddB|Sf^vg@ng@prFhu@pmE|G`eC~OrnBqSxeArd@dzApGps@_u@flAxApd@p}@`{@zRre@`Kt`HaPbhBlEd|@cFvqBdRr`ByFre@UvhE_uAt|C__@bAk`@en@k{@tHosAcl@q_BtHexDf{AopBj|AyRhhCk[tlI`Kb^qBjaFmx@pkIvKnvDkQhmAj@hmAbAlTmQlTnLxv@xAl}AqNtu@lLjnAeMtyDpBbyAe^jaFbAz|AlFhtAka@`zCqo@nr@ueB_\\_w@fXmeAp{@iDj_Aoc@rs@s[~`Dxc@xyBtEz|AmRl_Ds`@n_BbGdwE~_BdwBfN|uAka@`gEwQzyEsIntBykAjgA}Nn{EczBntEoj@heDm]}DomCpfE{YlnAgyIjnAut@qnBooDvg@yYse@efk@fpK_uBtjDs|c@xqH}yAucAeXf|FkrG~wRjNpfEtgAv}CpR|fGifAfiHgh@v|CsTnUabA`dC');
  var decodedLevels = decodeLevels("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB");

  var setRegion = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: decodedPath,
    levels: decodedLevels,
    strokeColor: '#8A8000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#8A8A1D',
    fillOpacity: 0,
    map: map
  });
}

function decodeLevels(encodedLevelsString) {
  var decodedLevels = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < encodedLevelsString.length; ++i) {
    var level = encodedLevelsString.charCodeAt(i) - 63;
    decodedLevels.push(level);
  }
  return decodedLevels;
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Comment: There's still a discrepancy between my original line and the resulting fiddle. It's visible when the map is zoomed in, in the visinity of Pointe-au-Chene, QC (eastern tip).

Comment: You sure that isn't in the original data?  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2x6eLLca/4/)

Comment: Yes, the utility didn't have that discrepancy. That being said, I moved some of the points around, got the updated encoded string, replaced / to // and it now represents the borders spot on. Thank you.